# Oracle temp table count is wrong using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have below DB Objects and Java program,
When I try to call stored procedures of Oracle from Java, am not able to get temp table count.Am missing something but I don't know what's wrong.Please help me to find the error in code.When I call the procedures using oracle statements directly in oracle SQL developer am able to get count of temp table.After each time calling insert procedure it inserts and gets count properly in Oracle statements call and Java.But When I try the same using JDBC only insert procedure returns count but get count of temp table is missing the count and retruns Zero instead of One.

**Temp table :**

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABLE1_TMP(NAME VARCHAR2(10)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

**Procedures:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_TABLE1_TMP(IN_NAME IN VARCHAR2,TEMP_COUNT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IN_NAME:'||IN_NAME);
 INSERT INTO TABLE1_TMP VALUES(IN_NAME);
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TEMP_COUNT FROM TABLE1_TMP;
END INSERT_TABLE1_TMP;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETCNT_TABLE1_TMP(TEMP_COUNT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN    
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TEMP_COUNT FROM TABLE1_TMP;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT:'||TEMP_COUNT);
END GETCNT_TABLE1_TMP;
```

**Execution :**

```
DECLARE
  IN_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
  TEMP_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IN_NAME := 'name1';

  INSERT_TABLE1_TMP(
    IN_NAME => IN_NAME,
    TEMP_COUNT => TEMP_COUNT
  );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('insert TEMP_COUNT1 = ' || TEMP_COUNT);
  GETCNT_TABLE1_TMP(
    TEMP_COUNT => TEMP_COUNT
  );

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEMP_COUNT2 = ' || TEMP_COUNT);
END;
```

**Output :**

```
IN_NAME:name1
insert TEMP_COUNT1 = 1
COUNT:1
TEMP_COUNT2 = 1
```

Java Program :

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
CallableStatement callableStatement1 = null;

try {
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall("{call insert_table1_tmp(?,?)}");

    callableStatement.setString(1, "name1");        
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.NUMBER); 
    callableStatement.executeUpdate();          
    System.out.println("Insert into temp table count :"+callableStatement.getInt(2));

    callableStatement1 = dbConnection.prepareCall("{call  getCnt_table1_tmp(?)}");           
    callableStatement1.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER); 
    callableStatement1.execute();           
    System.out.println("Temp table count :"+callableStatement1.getInt(1));

} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

} finally {             

    if (callableStatement != null) {
        callableStatement.close();
    }
    if (callableStatement1 != null) {
        callableStatement1.close();
    }

    if (dbConnection != null) {
        dbConnection.commit();
        dbConnection.close();
    }

}
```

**Java Output :**

```
Insert into temp table count :1
Temp table count :0
```

Comment: is autocommit true or false for this connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABLE1_TMP(NAME VARCHAR2(10)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Per our discussion, your temporary table deletes rows on commit.  If the JDBC driver autocommit is set to true, then you will have zero rows when you query the table later.